# PHP Sums minus value

Tags: php, woocommerce, sum

I have the following sum

```
$item_shipping_cost += (float) $this->get_fee( $this->fee, $item_shipping_cost ) * (int) $product_data['quantity'];
```

This adds up like the this:

> Product Price + Item Shipping Cost + Fee * Qty

So if the product price is set at £1.00 and Item Shipping is at £1.00 and the fee is £0.50 and I want 2 items the cost will be a total of £4.00. However, I would like to subtract the value of 'fee' as I only want the fee to be charge on addition products. How would I do this?

This line of code belongs to a WooCommerce Shipping Per Product plugin. The full code is:

```
class WC_Shipping_Per_Product extends WC_Shipping_Method {

const METHOD_ID = 'per_product';

/**
 * Default product shipping cost.
 *
 * @var int
 */
private $cost;

/**
 * Handling fee applied to entire order.
 *
 * @var int
 */
private $order_fee;

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param int $instance_id Instance Id for method in zone config.
 */
public function __construct( $instance_id = 0 ) {
    parent::__construct( $instance_id );
    $this->id                 = self::METHOD_ID;
    $this->method_title       = __( 'Per-product', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' );
    $this->method_description = __( 'Per product shipping allows you to define different shipping costs for products, based on customer location. These costs will be displayed and charged separately from any other shipping methods.', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' );
    $this->supports           = array(
        'shipping-zones',
        'instance-settings',
        'instance-settings-modal',
    );
    // Load the form fields.
    $this->init_form_fields();

    // Define user set variables.
    $this->title      = $this->get_option( 'title' );
    $this->tax_status = $this->get_option( 'tax_status' );
    $this->cost       = $this->get_option( 'cost' );
    $this->fee        = $this->get_option( 'fee' );
    $this->order_fee  = $this->get_option( 'order_fee' );

    // Actions.
    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
}

/**
 * Initialise Gateway Settings Form Fields.
 */
public function init_form_fields() {
    $this->instance_form_fields = array(
        'title'      => array(
            'title'       => __( 'Method Title', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'type'        => 'text',
            'description' => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'default'     => __( 'Product Shipping', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'desc_tip'    => true,
        ),
        'tax_status' => array(
            'title'       => __( 'Tax Status', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'type'        => 'select',
            'description' => '',
            'default'     => 'taxable',
            'options'     => array(
                'taxable' => __( 'Taxable', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
                'none'    => __( 'None', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            ),
        ),
        'cost'       => array(
            'title'       => __( 'Default Product Cost', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'type'        => 'text',
            'description' => __( 'Cost excluding tax (per product) for products without defined costs. Enter an amount, e.g. 2.50. Entering an amount here will apply a global shipping cost for all products, effectively disabling all other shipping methods', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'default'     => '',
            'placeholder' => __( 'Disabled, Enter an amount, e.g. 2.50.', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'desc_tip'    => true,
        ),
        'fee'        => array(
            'title'       => __( 'Handling Fee (per product)', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'type'        => 'text',
            'description' => __( 'Fee excluding tax. Enter an amount, e.g. 2.50, or a percentage, e.g. 5%. Leave blank to disable.', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'default'     => '',
            'placeholder' => __( 'Disabled, Enter an amount, e.g. 2.50, or a percentage, e.g. 5%.', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'desc_tip'    => true,
        ),
        'order_fee'  => array(
            'title'       => __( 'Handling Fee (per order)', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'type'        => 'text',
            'description' => __( 'Fee excluding tax. Enter an amount, e.g. 2.50, or a percentage, e.g. 5%. Leave blank to disable.', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'default'     => '',
            'placeholder' => __( 'Disabled, Enter an amount, e.g. 2.50, or a percentage, e.g. 5%.', 'woocommerce-shipping-per-product' ),
            'desc_tip'    => true,
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Check is per product shipping is enabled for the product.
 *
 * @param array $product_data The product data form the package array.
 * @param array $package Shipping package array.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function is_per_product_shipping_product( array $product_data, array $package ) {
    if ( $product_data['quantity'] > 0 ) {
        if ( $product_data['data']->needs_shipping() ) {

            if ( false !== $this->calculate_product_shipping_cost( $product_data, $package ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Calculate the per product shipping cost if enabled for the product.
 *
 * @param array $product_data The product data form the package array.
 * @param array $package Shipping package array.
 *
 * @return float|bool
 */
private function calculate_product_shipping_cost( array $product_data, array $package ) {

    $rule               = false;
    $item_shipping_cost = 0;

    if ( $product_data['variation_id'] ) {
        $rule = woocommerce_per_product_shipping_get_matching_rule( $product_data['variation_id'], $package );
    }

    if ( false === $rule ) {
        $rule = woocommerce_per_product_shipping_get_matching_rule( $product_data['product_id'], $package );
    }

    if ( $rule ) {
        $item_shipping_cost += (float) $rule->rule_item_cost * (int) $product_data['quantity'];
        $item_shipping_cost += (float) $rule->rule_cost;
    } elseif ( '0' === $this->cost || $this->cost > 0 ) {
        // Use default shipping cost.
        $item_shipping_cost += (float) $this->cost * (int) $product_data['quantity'];
    } else {
        // NO default and nothing found - abort.
        return false;
    }

    // Fee.
    $item_shipping_cost += (float) $this->get_fee( $this->fee, $item_shipping_cost ) * (int) $product_data['quantity'];

    return $item_shipping_cost;
}

/**
 * Calculate shipping when this method is used standalone.
 *
 * @param array $package information.
 */
public function calculate_shipping( $package = array() ) {
    $_tax          = new WC_Tax();
    $taxes         = array();
    $shipping_cost = 0;

    if ( empty( $package['ship_via'] ) || ! in_array( $this->id, $package['ship_via'], true ) ) {
        return;  // must be a package mark as per product shipping in split_shipping_packages_per_product.
    }

    // This shipping method loops through products, adding up the cost.
    if ( count( $package['contents'] ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item_id => $values ) {
            if ( $values['quantity'] > 0 ) {
                if ( $values['data']->needs_shipping() ) {

                    $item_shipping_cost = $this->calculate_product_shipping_cost( $values, $package );
                    $shipping_cost     += $item_shipping_cost;

                    if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_calc_taxes' ) && 'taxable' === $this->tax_status ) {
                        $rates      = $_tax->get_shipping_tax_rates( $values['data']->get_tax_class() );
                        $item_taxes = $_tax->calc_shipping_tax( $item_shipping_cost, $rates );

                        // Sum the item taxes.
                        foreach ( array_keys( $taxes + $item_taxes ) as $key ) {
                            $taxes[ $key ] = ( isset( $item_taxes[ $key ] ) ? $item_taxes[ $key ] : 0 ) + ( isset( $taxes[ $key ] ) ? $taxes[ $key ] : 0 );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Add order shipping cost + tax.
    if ( $this->order_fee ) {
        $order_fee = (float) $this->get_fee( $this->order_fee, $shipping_cost );

        $shipping_cost += $order_fee;
        if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_calc_taxes' ) && 'taxable' === $this->tax_status ) {
            $rates      = $_tax->get_shipping_tax_rates();
            $item_taxes = $_tax->calc_shipping_tax( $order_fee, $rates );

            // Sum the item taxes.
            foreach ( array_keys( $taxes + $item_taxes ) as $key ) {
                $taxes[ $key ] = ( isset( $item_taxes[ $key ] ) ? $item_taxes[ $key ] : 0 ) + ( isset( $taxes[ $key ] ) ? $taxes[ $key ] : 0 );
            }
        }
    }

    // Add rate.
    $this->add_rate(
        array(
            'id'    => $this->id,
            'label' => $this->title,
            'cost'  => $shipping_cost,
            'taxes' => $taxes, // We calc tax in the method.
        )
    );
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly signifies "addition products" in your code?  Writing an `if` statement is easy; understanding your requirements isn't.

Comment: @mickmackusa the fee is based on 'per product' which is why it's *QTY I would like it to subtract 1*the fee value so it's not charged on every QTY just on QTY above 1.

Comment: So you are asking if `$qty > 1` then subtract `($qty - 1) * $fee`?

Comment: Thank you, yes - I didn't really know how to explain it :)

Comment: Your question could use a more descriptive title and a better description of your requirements using the `£1.00` and `£1.00` example.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean:

```
$item_shipping_cost -= ($product_data['quantity'] - 1) * $this->fee;
```

This will remove fees from all products except one.

Add my line of code after your line:

> ```
> $item_shipping_cost += (float) $this->get_fee( $this->fee, $item_shipping_cost ) * (int) $product_data['quantity'];
> ```

When there is only 1 product, then no fee will be subtracted.

Comment: Thanks, I tried replacing that code but it didn't do anything so I suppose there's somewhere else within that file that works this out?

Comment: I didn't mean for my snippet to replace any of your code.  It is an additional line of code.  ...and I don't know where you wrote it.  Show me a 3v4l.org demo link.

Comment: You can download the whole plugin here https://gofile.io/d/VwcV8U which has the files that would need editing.

Comment: I don't enjoy scrolling through all of that on my phone either.  Show me where you wrote my line of code into your code by copy-pasting into 3v4l.org then send me that link.

Comment: I don't know what to fix.  That is exactly what you should do.  Now I am not sure that you are testing it properly.